# Error while creating and downloading PDF using ItextSharp in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razorpdf

I have tried to make Pdf from razor views.But it always error me.
I have used Visual studio 2013, .net framework 4.5 & asp.net mvc5.

For creating i have used to install RazorPdf version 1.0.0.0 package & itextsharp 5.5.2.0 version.

Code snapshot----------

```
    //controller code
    public PdfResult Pdf()
    {
        return new PdfResult();
    }

    //razor view

   @{
   Layout = null;
    }

<itext creationdate="@DateTime.Now.ToString()" producer="RazorPDF">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0.5" cellspacing="0.5"   widths="30;70"    borderwidth="1.0" left="false" right="false" top="false"  bottom="false" red="0" green="0" blue="0">
    <row>
        <cell>
            <chunk style="font-weight:bold;">Today:</chunk>
        </cell>
        <cell>
            <chunk style="">@DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")</chunk>
        </cell>
    </row>
    <row>
        <cell>
            <chunk style="font-weight:bold;">Yesterday:</chunk>
        </cell>
        <cell>
            <chunk style="">@DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")</chunk>
        </cell>
    </row>
</table>
```

----------------------Error Details---------------

Could not load type 'iTextSharp.text.html.HtmlParser' from assembly 'itextsharp, Version=5.5.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8354ae6d2174ddca'

Answer (score 1):

1. Firstly remove the tag itext above your table.
2. Then create new layout in shared folder.
3. In that layout just copy and paste below code

> ```
> <itext creationdate="@DateTime.Now.ToString()" producer="RazorPDF">
>     @RenderBody()
> </itext>
> ```

4. Then set `Layout = "~/Views/Shared/NewlyCreatedLayout.cshtml";`

   Hope this will help.